# Criterion for a convex cone to be nonempty

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to proof the following criterion for a convex cone $M=\{x\in\Bbb R^n|Ax=b,x\ge0\}$, where $A\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$, $b\in \Bbb R^m$ and $b\ge0$, to be not empty:

> $M\neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \space(\inf_{y \in \Bbb R^m}e^Ty$  subject to the constraints $Ax+y=b, x\ge0, y\ge0)=0$

Where $e=(1..1)^T\in \Bbb R^m$ and $"\ge"$ denotes componentwise inequality.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum I know that, but I have no idea how to do this and therefore I asked here for help.